# How do you set the first option as default in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Using the `ngFor` directive in a `<select>` `<option>`, I'd like to use the first option in a list as the default one if the `ngModel` is not populated. The Angular <=4 solutions I find (like using `[selected]`) apparently no longer work.

Here's the code:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="favoriteSnack">
  <option *ngFor="let snack of opts" [value]="snack">{{snack}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers out there for Angular 4, but things have changed since then. This is what I came up with.

```
<select [ngModel]="favoriteSnack ? favoriteSnack : opts[0]"
        (ngModelChange)="favoriteSnack = $event">
  <option *ngFor="let snack of opts" [value]="snack">{{snack}}</option>
</select>
```

If there is a better answer I'd be glad to see it!

Comment: You could initialize `favoriteSnack` to the first value when you populate the `opts` array in code. That would allow to use two-way binding. Please note that `[ngModelChange]` should be `(ngModelChange)`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Nice catch! For my real-world application, however, both the the options and selection are populated by the server and are decoupled from each other in the domain model. Setting the default value from there would be difficult (and maybe a bad practice?), so I am keeping what I have. Great addition/observation, though!

Comment: Can you show in the question how you get `opts` and `favoriteSnack`?

Comment: This example is an adaptation of a business sample that I can't share, so pulling all that in to update will be tedious and time-consuming. I may try to do it later, though. Sorry!

I do see where you're going, though. To try and paint a picture, the `opts` are loaded from the server when the application loads, and the objects that would hold `favoriteSnack` are loaded much later and in various contexts. I could, upon loading the `favoriteSnack` container object, check `favoriteSnack` for `null` and populate it with `opts[0]`. It would certainly keep the template file cleaner.